# Using the table_data_range function within the flatten function in big query

Tags: google-bigquery, flatten

In Big Query I have used the table wildcard function TABLE_DATE_RANGE successfully in previous queries, such as `FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([89571105.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01'), TIMESTAMP('2015-02-10'))`.

However, I now need to flatten the output as the result of some additional fields I need to output.  In an effort to do this I wrapped the table wildcard function with the flatten function like so: `FROM (FLATTEN( TABLE_DATE_RANGE([89571105.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2015-02-01'), TIMESTAMP('2015-02-10')),customDimensions) )`

The result is the error message `"Error: Not found: Table ... 679:89571105.ga_sessions_".`  Is there a way to wrap the table wildcard function with the flatten function to get the needed output?

Comment: This is not possible yet, it's on the feature list: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=106 an alternative is also listed there.